# OpenSSL without -CApath for APNs

Tags: openssl, apn

I'm trying to verify my .pem certificate and connect to Apple's APN gateway to see if it's working correctly. However, when I run

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert data/certs/production.pem -debug -showcerts
```

I get an error like this:

```
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

My OpenSSL dir is located here:

```
$ openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

So when I explicitly point the directory in the command line (-CApath) suddenly it seems to be working:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert data/certs/production.pem -debug -showcerts -CApath /usr/lib/ssl/certs/
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

I've tried running `c_rehash /usr/lib/ssl/certs`, but it didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong? I'd like it to run without pointing to the -CApath everytime, because I suspect this is the reason why my push notifications are not being sent.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> I'm trying to verify my .pem certificate and connect to
>  Apple's APN gateway to see if it's working correctly.
> However, when I run
>
> $ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195
>       -cert data/certs/production.pem -debug -showcerts
>
> I get an error like this:
>
> error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
> ```

You are missing a root certificate, and you can specify it with `-CAfile`. Once you specify `CAfile`, the chain will verify.

However, you will encounter a handshake alert after you fix the root certificate issue. I believe its a client certificate issue caused by me not having one. Below, 0x14094410 is the OpenSSL error, and the SSL error (from the TLS protocol) is simply `SSL alert number 40`. Alert 40 is the handshake alert, and there's no additional information.

**First**

Determine the root you need:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, O = "Entrust, Inc.", OU = www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference, OU = "(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.", CN = Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
140633516213928:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1257:SSL alert number 40
140633516213928:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
```

So you need *Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)*. You can download it from [Entrust Root Certificates](https://www.entrust.net/downloads/root_index.cfm). Its named `entrust_2048_ca.cer` and it appears to be in PEM format.

**Second**

Now, run `oepnssl s_client` again, but this time with `-CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer`. Notice it completes with a `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`:

```
$ openssl s_client -tls1 -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 O = Entrust.net, OU = www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.), OU = (c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited, CN = Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = "Entrust, Inc.", OU = www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference, OU = "(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.", CN = Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Cupertino, O = Apple Inc., OU = iTMS Engineering, CN = gateway.push.apple.com
verify return:1
139719745095336:error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1257:SSL alert number 40
139719745095336:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
   i:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
 1 s:/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
   i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFEzCCA/ugAwIBAgIETBzSBzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBsTELMAkGA1UEBhMC
VVMxFjAUBgNVBAoTDUVudHJ1c3QsIEluYy4xOTA3BgNVBAsTMHd3dy5lbnRydXN0
Lm5ldC9ycGEgaXMgaW5jb3Jwb3JhdGVkIGJ5IHJlZmVyZW5jZTEfMB0GA1UECxMW
KGMpIDIwMDkgRW50cnVzdCwgSW5jLjEuMCwGA1UEAxMlRW50cnVzdCBDZXJ0aWZp
Y2F0aW9uIEF1dGhvcml0eSAtIEwxQzAeFw0xMjA1MDMxODIyMjhaFw0xNDA1MzEw
OTI5MDZaMIGHMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTESMBAG
A1UEBxMJQ3VwZXJ0aW5vMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpBcHBsZSBJbmMuMRkwFwYDVQQLExBp
VE1TIEVuZ2luZWVyaW5nMR8wHQYDVQQDExZnYXRld2F5LnB1c2guYXBwbGUuY29t
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAt4u3gyk9GeQGIH7pmYSA
604LxMLvaUZkgeXOLRzH/48LZgPD5megHhsvjj6du2xzOQKb7iCVYF4HnHf3k00R
3iXtvEmqRU87uw8K2LPu9ZfoNcJpu2e45eF27dXjvjCmvlMDsPxFBer9nAex3P4o
mGCld73SfcZuIB3bQ6BFTIM6je+0nNwP9yuSF4XjOrOx+1+ifgGwyl9T/qa1TYWW
K/LmObAmpbBYwklu33NVOR4BBrZ+GAdj1irdZqh3s3R+b/ANaAAbx2YYrScnIP15
OG7oYNKO3zzIQ0KaBjJjv30j5dXFQaIiphUWhuhQ3rRMmG7xV5UWVqHMriMLD4bS
PQIDAQABo4IBWTCCAVUwCwYDVR0PBAQDAgWgMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMB
BggrBgEFBQcDAjAzBgNVHR8ELDAqMCigJqAkhiJodHRwOi8vY3JsLmVudHJ1c3Qu
bmV0L2xldmVsMWMuY3JsMGUGCCsGAQUFBwEBBFkwVzAjBggrBgEFBQcwAYYXaHR0
cDovL29jc3AuZW50cnVzdC5uZXQwMAYIKwYBBQUHMAKGJGh0dHA6Ly9haWEuZW50
cnVzdC5uZXQvbDFjLWNoYWluLmNlcjBABgNVHSAEOTA3MDUGCSqGSIb2fQdLAjAo
MCYGCCsGAQUFBwIBFhpodHRwOi8vd3d3LmVudHJ1c3QubmV0L3JwYTAfBgNVHSME
GDAWgBQe8auJBvhJDwEzd+4Ueu4ZfJMoTTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQULkkf+RyRucrBgaw2
Iu+V+aUctU4wCQYDVR0TBAIwADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAPSQnfPByAF+Y
ML2kwujhbKMZw81oF3HGkdSG756Jt5cqiBJB+KS+4ZThpTgAr9EytfHtl4NPoBwZ
I0a2gLvmO2HNe5OqVSdOqyPCCFN0aBZTYwLVHM3HmoUbPn+Zh19g7Me4AC69IR9i
RoJmzSkagR+Z7z7veiSzfeUHaGa0YUsyc7iMerF1rFfYJvXFVp4D1gA672nTzctZ
0e0yItFXJrN6FL/K+NKCk/O3HCn95oVEPtnEWF2Qm91AZKoCYV1u3VzWtlZsyjQL
wqfQNpr+VUe1SQ1DInr2enCQrCBnH7R3JVscj91cfEiH1SydpRrNFICT40nphEWK
higEADTWUQ==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Cupertino/O=Apple Inc./OU=iTMS Engineering/CN=gateway.push.apple.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2675 bytes and written 338 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 53E341FB8A63D8F2BDB1DA4B750116C6...
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1398721822
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```